# Python Unittest shortDescription printing out None

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I found out about the `shortDescription` function and was eager to try it out.

> shortDescription()
>   Returns a description of the test, or None if no description has been provided. The default implementation of this method returns the first line of the test method’s docstring, if available, or None.

Strangely enough, I can't get it to work.
Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

My class does inherit from `unittest.TestCase` and even it has a docstring

```
def test_smth(self):
    """
    TEST
    """
    self.description = 'TEST!'
    print(self.shortDescription())
```

Prints out `None` in Python 3.6

Comment: Try to put the line `TEST` on the first line of the docstring: `"""TEST<newline>other stuff<newline>"""`...

Comment: Also, is `test_smth()` a method of your class?  Where is the `self` parameter?

Comment: Betcha it works once you do these things.

Comment: The lack of `self` was a typo when writing it here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first line of the doc-string is empty:

```
"""   <--- this is the first line
TEST
"""
```

By removing the first empty line, you will see what you want:

```
"""TEST
"""
```

---

```
➜  /tmp cat t.py
import unittest

class UT(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_smth(self):
        """TEST"""
        print('shortDescription():', self.shortDescription())


unittest.main()
➜  /tmp python3.6 t.py
shortDescription(): TEST
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

If you run tests with `-v` command line option, you can see the description printed instead of the test method name:

```
➜  /tmp python3.6 t.py -v
test_smth (__main__.UT)
TEST ... shortDescription(): TEST
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing `self` in your function argument.
Rest of the things are good to go.
Try it out.